# Why is the phrase parent-in-law and not parent-by-law?

Tags: etymology

Since it's due to the law that they are his/her parents by proxy, why isn't the phrase 'by-law' instead of 'in-law'?

Answer (score 2):

The question came up in Stack Exchange ELU :
[ELU "Where's in-law in mother-in-law from"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/wheres-in-law-in-mother-in-law-from)

The second answer shows the OED etymology, which mentions "in the eye of the canon law".

The phrase "in the eye of the law" in general is very common:
[Google books "in the eye of the law"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&biw=1082&bih=674&tbm=bks&ei=UDMHX8KTG4XctAaYip2YAw&q=%22in%20the%20eye%20of%20the%20law%22&oq=%22in%20the%20eye%20of%20the%20law%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299k1l2.262955.278434.0.279072.50.37.13.0.0.0.175.2960.31j6.37.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.45.2609...0j0i13k1j33i10i299k1.0.AydLiZC4u9I)

Just searching for "in law" produces this google definition
"at (or in) law: according to or concerned with the laws of a country."
so the preposition "in" is sometimes used with "law" in this sense.

The use of "in law" in "parent-in-law" has a lot of precedent and is not an oddity. The phrase "by law" is common too, but it isn't used in this context.